# Encryption data keys in single file at same location

Tags: encryption, aes, rsa

I have an external storage which I am wanting to store encrypted files.

Each file is AES encrypted with its own data key, and all of the data keys are saved into a single keys.json file at the same storage location as all of the encrypted files.

The keys.json file is AES encrypted using a main key.

The main key is encrypted using a users RSA public key.

When I want to share the files with another user I encrypt the main key using the new users RSA public key.

Is this strategy ok?

My main concern is the keys.json file containing ALL of the data keys for ALL of the files on the storage location.

Comment: "OK" is too broad. It depends on what access you want users to have. Do you want everyone to have access to everything? Do you want to be able to revoke access in any way? Do you want them to have access to new things that are added? What kinds of attacks are you concerned about? Are the encrypted files of high value? What kinds of resources are likely to be expended to get to those resources? What criteria will you use for "ok?" (In any case this is off topic for SO; you want security.stackexchange.com, but you'll need to think about these questions in order to ask there.)

Comment: Stackoverflow is for [programming questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Questions about **security design or cryptography** are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/) or [Crypto](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks Rob & James for the clarification.